# How to get content from an editable div tag in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

After edit the content in frontend, how can I get the content in backend?
asdf.InnerHtml does not work, I mean it won't return new content that I entered in but just what it has on page first load. I need html content of that div.

Comment: That's because the content is only on the front end once the page is served.  You'll need a little more detail if you want a solution for your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to do something like this is to use javascript to place the content into a hidden text box.

Once the page has posted back, this value is available on the server.

So you want to place [one of these](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield.aspx) on your page, which you can manipulate however you want client side, and it will be submitted to the server when posted back.

It would look something like (on the client):

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" name="html" value="">
```

Javascript:

```
 getElementById('<%=hidden.ClientID%>').value = asdf.InnerHtml
```

Then check the value server side.

Comment: I need html content of the div

Comment: So you would set the value of the hidden text box to be the 'html content of the div'

Answer (score 0):

I am not positive this will work but what if you gave the div a name attribute  .  Then in the backend you might be able to get the contents with Request["someName"].

If not, you could definately put a runat="server" hidden html input element in the page and after the edit use javascript to place the contents of the div into the value of the hidden input.

Comment: Your first solution wouldn't work as it won't be POST to the server, I agree with your second solution.

Answer (score 0):

The value should be being posted to the server assuming you have `run="server"` on the div element.

You can make a quick hack on the server side page load to set the InnerHTML of your div.

```
if(Request.Params(myDiv.ClientID) != null)
    myDiv.InnerHtml = Request.Params(myDiv.ClientID);
```